# Why does my update query doesnt work in c# with sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

when I try to update my database it crashes when it reaches the datetime column.

Here is the function that I'm trying to execute (pub Date is where its crashing):

```
        public void UpdateDatabase(List<Title> titleList, List<Author> authorList, List<Publisher> publisherList)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("CsharpMD3")))
            {
                foreach (var item in titleList)
                {

                    connection.Execute($"update titles Set title='{item.title}', titleType='{item.TitleType}', price='{item.Price}' , pubdate=cast({item.PubDate.Year}{item.PubDate.Month}{item.PubDate.Day} as datetime2) , pubID='{item.PubID}' where ID={item.ID}");                    
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried casting it as datetime2/datetime, I have tried using the convert function

```
CONVERT(datetime, mydate, 112)
```

I have tried to just put int the whole date but that also crashes when it starts reading the time.
I have tried this:

```
connection.Execute($"update titles Set title='{item.title}', titleType='{item.TitleType}', price='{item.Price}' , pubdate='{item.PubDate.Year}{item.PubDate.Month}{item.PubDate.Day}' , pubID='{item.PubID}' where ID={item.ID}");
```

I also tried adding and removing apostrophes.

Mostly the errors I get are: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
and : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

And the weird thing is that it works when I try to create(insert) a new item into the database
It also works if I type in the command into the sql itself with variable names changed to the numbers:

```
        public void InsertTitle(Title toInsert)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("CsharpMD3")))
            {
                connection.Execute($"insert into dbo.titles (title, titleType, price, pubdate, pubID) VALUES ('{toInsert.title}' , '{toInsert.TitleType}', '{toInsert.Price}', '{toInsert.PubDate.Year}{toInsert.PubDate.Month}{toInsert.PubDate.Day}', '{toInsert.PubID}')");
            }
        }
```

I have also tried the parametariezed sql commands, but that didnt work out for me, so I just want to figure out why the update function doesnt work.

It also works if I just change the year and not the month or day!

Comment: Yikes, this is scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: I would like to know better why _tried parameterized commands, but that didnt work out for me_ As you do now you are passing everything as strings and apart from the sql  injection problem your code could fail for simple parsing errors, what if your title value contains a single quote?. Also with dapper you could simply pass the object to the execute command if the fields have the same names as the properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fix the issue, and also fix the gaping-wide security hole in the original:

```
public void UpdateDatabase(IEnumerable<Title> titleList)
{
    string sql = "update titles Set title= @title, titleType= @titleType, price= @price , pubdate= @pubDate , pubID= @pubID where ID= @ID";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("CsharpMD3")))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        //Use actual column types and lengths from the DB here.
        // I had to guess, but you can look them up.
        command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        command.Parameters.Add("@titleType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal, 6, 2);
        command.Parameters.Add("@pubDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
        command.Parameters.Add("@pubID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);

        connection.Open();
        foreach (var item in titleList)
        {
            command.Parameters["@title"].Value = item.title;
            command.Parameters["@titleType"].Value = item.TitleType;
            command.Parameters["@price"].Value = item.Price;
            command.Parameters["@pubDate"].Value = item.PubDate;
            command.Parameters["@pubID"].Value = item.PubID;
            command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = item.ID;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        }
    }
}
```

and the insert function:

```
public int InsertTitle(Title toInsert)
{
    string sql = "insert into dbo.titles (title, titleType, price, pubdate, pubID) VALUES (@title, @titleType, @price, @pubDate, @pubID);select scope_identity();";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("CsharpMD3")))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = toInsert.title;
        command.Parameters.Add("@titleType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = toInsert.titleType;
        command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal, 6, 2).Value = toInsert.Price;
        command.Parameters.Add("@pubDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = toInsert.PubDate;
        command.Parameters.Add("@pubID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = toInsert.PubID;

        connection.Open();
        toInsert.ID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        return toInsert.ID;
    }
}
```

It's a good rule of thumb that if you ever find yourself trying to format a date value for use in an SQL string from *any* client language platform,  you're doing something **horribly wrong**.

As for the original issue... I expect you had single-digit values in places that ended up creating nonsensical date strings, such as `2019123`. That could be January 23rd or December 3rd, and there's no way to know which.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, also makes sense why my orriginal approach didnt work with the single digit dates.